# Strtol function returning wrong value

Tags: c, string, strtol

I need to get a credit card number as input on an exercise, to dos so I'm ussing the function fgets (getting it as a string to check if it is realy a number) and then strtol to make it a long integer. But the integer value return by the function does not match the one on the string.

```
while (*endptr != '\n') {
        char card_number_string[20];
        char *endptr;
        long int card_number;

        printf("Number: ");
        fgets(card_number_string, 20, stdin);
        card_number = strtol(card_number_string, &endptr, 10);
        printf("Result: %ld", card_number);
    }
```

For example, when I input the value 4003600000000014 the output of the strtol shown in the printf is 2147483647.

Is it a bug on my code? Or the function does return something different like this??

Note: All the variables are declared on top of the main function, they are in there just to know how they were declared

Comment: I think it is better to use string (`char` array) for card number instead of numeric variable. Imagine that first 2 digits are 00.

Comment: I am using integer because in this particular problem the input never starts with 0

Comment: In some cases the data looks like numeric but in fact is string even if all characters are digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value is outside `long` range.  2147483647 is the max value of `long` in your case.

Use `long long`. (or `unsigned long long` if negative CC# are not needed)

```
    //long int card_number;
    long long card_number;

    printf("Number: ");
    fgets(card_number_string, 20, stdin);
    
    //card_number = strtol(card_number_string, &endptr, 10);
    card_number = strtoll(card_number_string, &endptr, 10);

    //printf("Result: %ld", card_number);
    printf("Result: %lld", card_number);
```

---

Note: `char *endptr;` shadows the `endptr` in `while (*endptr != '\n')`

Comment: I checked, via the limits.h the max long value is 9804467591446527. And using a long long variable the output of the function is still wrong. About the char what does it mean that it shadows?

Comment: "using a long long variable the output of the function is still wrong."  --> and what was that wrong output?  Did code use `strtoll()`  (2 ells) and `"%lld"`?

Comment: @LuísOtávio When `while (*endptr != '\n') {` is executed, the `endptr` used is not the new `endptr` defined inside the loop: `char *endptr;`.

Comment: It was outputing the same value, but i was still using `strtol()` and not `strtoll()`. Now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Ohh aboout the endpt, i put it in the wrong place on the snippet, it is originally on top of the main function, i wanted only to show my variables, I'll edit it, thanks!

Comment: Tip: avoid "just the right size" buffers for user input.  User input is evil.  Suggest at least 2x what you think a sane user would need.

Comment: Editing the code after answers arrive is poor SO etiquette.  It this case, roll-back and append a note at the end of the post explaining `endptr`.

Comment: I'm using low buffer because it is for automated online test and 19 is the maximum input size. For a real case I would be using a bigger buffer for sure.

Comment: `char *endptr; ... while (*endptr != '\n') {` is poor code. What is the value of `endptr` and `*endptr` the first time `while (*endptr != '\n')` is executed?  Good luck.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica thank you again! I started using the site recently and don't nknow much about etiquette rules

Comment: @LuísOtávio You could take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at it